# Jetpack Navigation - retrieve nested graph programatically

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I would like to retrieve nested graph programmatically to change `startDestination`.

that one works for navHost

```
val navHostFragment = appNavFragment as NavHostFragment
val inflater = navHostFragment.navController.navInflater
val graph = inflater.inflate(R.navigation.nav_app)
graph.startDestination = if(sth) startDestination1 else startDestination2

val navController = navHostFragment.navController

navController.graph = graph
```

And I would like to do the same for the nested graph, but I don't know how to retrieve it programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, for a nested graph I needed to use `findNode`

```
    val node = graph.findNode(R.id.nav_main)
    (node as NavGraph).startDestination = R.id.onboarding_dest
```